# BEAUTIFUL ANALYTICS CHART it doesn't work in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, raphael

I want test this example with MVC4

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beautiful Analytics Chart</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lib/prototype.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/lib/raphael.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/analytics.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='line-chart-holder'></div>
<table id="d1" style='display: none;'>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th>3/02</th>
         <th>3/03</th>
         <th>3/09</th>
         <th>3/16</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
<tbody class='data'>
   <tr>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>210</td>
      <td>490</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class='line1'>
   <tr>
      <td>70 Views</td>
      <td>70 Views</td>
      <td>210 Views</td>
      <td>490 Views</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class='line2'>
   <tr>
      <td>Mar 2nd 2011</td>
      <td>Mar 3rd 2011</td>
      <td>Mar 9th 2011</td>
      <td>Mar 16th 2011</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   Element.observe(window,'load', function(){
      var w = 840; // you can make this dynamic so it fits as you would like
      var linechart = Raphael('line-chart', w, 250); // init the raphael obj and give it a width plus height
      drawLine({ // call the drawLine function
         holder: linechart, // pass through the raphael obj
         data_holder: 'd2', // find the table data source by id
         mastercolor: '#01A8F0', // set the line color
         spewidth: w, // pass in the same width
         showarea: true, // show the area
         mousecoords: 'rect' // rect (uses blanket mode) | circle (pinpoints the points)
      });
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I take this example from http://joedesigns.com/labs/Beautiful-Analytics-Chart/.
When using Asp.net MVC4 it doesn't generate the svm, however if I use any html  editor and execute it works.

I added raphae.js using a nuget package, but prototype.js and analytics.js were added manaully  in Script folder.

any reason why itsn't working?

this is my layout view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script type='text/javascript' src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="~/Scripts/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="~/Scripts/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="~/Scripts/analytics.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    Element.observe(window, 'load', function () {
        var w = 840; // you can make this dynamic so it fits as you would like
        var linechart = Raphael('line-chart-holder', w, 250); // init the raphael obj and give it a width plus height
        drawLine({ // call the drawLine function
            holder: linechart, // pass through the raphael obj
            data_holder: 'd1', // find the table data source by id
            mastercolor: '#01A8F0', // set the line color
            spewidth: w, // pass in the same width
            showarea: true, // show the area
            mousecoords: 'rect' // rect (uses blanket mode) | circle (pinpoints the points)
        });
    });


    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">

        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and my index view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div id='line-chart-holder'></div>
<table id="d1" style='display: none;'>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>3/02</th>
            <th>3/03</th>
            <th>3/09</th>
            <th>3/16</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody class='data'>
        <tr>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>210</td>
            <td>490</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class='line1'>
        <tr>
            <td>70 Views</td>
            <td>70 Views</td>
            <td>210 Views</td>
            <td>490 Views</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class='line2'>
        <tr>
            <td>Mar 2nd 2011</td>
            <td>Mar 3rd 2011</td>
            <td>Mar 9th 2011</td>
            <td>Mar 16th 2011</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: would you like to show your mvc relevant code, how we are supposed to help?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I added the code, i use project  template for create Asp.net MVC applications

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Although I would like understand Why when I add the analytic.js the Script folder and referenced in the header did not work?

The solution to my problem was put the code of analytic.js in my index view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div id='line-chart-holder'></div>
<table id="d1" style='display: none;'>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>3/02</th>
            <th>3/03</th>
            <th>3/09</th>
            <th>3/16</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody class='data'>
        <tr>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>210</td>
            <td>490</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class='line1'>
        <tr>
            <td>70 Views</td>
            <td>70 Views</td>
            <td>210 Views</td>
            <td>490 Views</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class='line2'>
        <tr>
            <td>Mar 2nd 2011</td>
            <td>Mar 3rd 2011</td>
            <td>Mar 9th 2011</td>
            <td>Mar 16th 2011</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type='text/javascript'>

....///Code of analytic.js////// http://joedesigns.com/labs/Beautiful-Analytics-Chart/js/analytics.js
</script>
```